# Plotting data after fitting it to exponential function

Tags: plotting, fitting

I am trying to plot `h` vs `t` such that `h` fits a equation `p = h*exp (-h*t)` using the code as given below

```
data = {{0.01148, 1}, {0.01451, 2}, {0.01704, 3}, {0.02244, 5}, {0.02429, 7}};
expoF = Block [ {h = data [[All, 1]], t = data[[All, 2]], p}, p = h*Exp[-h*t]]
lp = ListLinePlot [expoF, PlotRange -> All]
```

However this plot doesnt start from 0 and only plots `h` vs `t` for `t` given in `data`. How can I make the plot start from zero and ensure it still fits equation `p = h*exp (-h*t)`?

[image: plot]

Comment: "only plots h vs t for t given in "data"" - no, `expoF` is a list of numbers and they are values for consecutive integers starting from 0. ListPlot does it by default for list of numbers (in opposite to list of points).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems reasonable to fit `h`.

```
h = Fit[Reverse /@ data, {1, t, t^2}, t];
Show[Plot[h*Exp[-h*t], {t, 0, 7}],
 ListLinePlot[Transpose[{data[[All, 2]], expoF}]]]
```

[image]